# What happens if use different ram chips?

Tags: memory, motherboard, performance-tuning, memory-timings, memory-speed

I have an Asus M4A785TD-V EVO Motherboard. Considering this,
What happens if I plugin 2 ram chips of different frequency and different latancies? Do both work independently at their respective configs or both have to sync at lower performance ?

Answer (score 0):

As said, the RAM will work at the slowest device's speed to maintain stability. This is why it is recommended everywhere to always install "matched pairs" of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

That motherboard should automatize individually each slot, so there shouldn't be any stability problems. Although it's not recommended and you can forget overcloking with that setting. Both memories will work at the slowest frequency. Maybe you'll have to tweak the voltages a bit if they are different.